# How to append NSData to NSData in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdata, nsmutabledata

I m going to append `NSData` to `NSData` in Objective-C.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 4):

```
 NSMutableData *first_data = [NSMutableData dataWithContentsOfURL:self.firstURL];
 NSMutableData *second_data = [NSMutableData dataWithContentsOfURL:self.secondURL];
 [first_data appendData:second_data];
 [first_data writeToURL:url atomically:YES];
```